# Single word for all knowledge?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means all human knowledge.

Preferably, the word would be a noun and could refer to knowledge abstractly, inclusive of that which is written and not.

It means all that which is known, not that which is not yet known, or can never be known. (The unknown unknowns.)

To clarify, I mean only all known knowledge.

This excludes encyclopedia as a word.

In context:

“All knowledge” is like a balloon in space. The more it fills with gas, the more it touches on the void: the unknown. Such is the paradox of “all knowledge”.

Comment: Do you mean all things which have *ever* been known (specifically, by *humans?*) or which are *currently* known? Or indeed, all things which in principle *could* be known, even if in practice they never are?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I mean all knowledge which we know we know, and know we don’t.

Comment: Knowledge itself is a blanket describing chiefly the possession of information. With the adjective all you already have the best word to express many ideas. Could you provide some context where you'd like to use such a term?

Comment: Could we be talking about 'consciousness'?

Comment: What about the unknown knowns? Things you didn't know you knew.

Comment: @AndySemyonov No, but close. Consciousness implies a state of active awareness by a being. I’m looking for something more objective which doesn’t need to be actively perceived to be correct.

Comment: @Mitch I’ve addressed that in other comments under the submitted answer.

Comment: You were supposed to respond "I didn't know about that"

Comment: I would be wary of using terms like "all knowledge": databases and books are filled with knowledge, materially.  Knowledge is known by definition. Otherwise, it ain't nothing.

Comment: Isn't that just *knowledge*, as @Andy suggests? The stuff that's not yet known *isn't* 'knowledge' (yet); the stuff that *is* known (regardless of whether it's written, oral or otherwise) *is* knowledge.

Comment: I think your mystery word could be likened to the word 'Light' as a metaphor. All knowledge is light.

Comment: all bodies of knowledge

Comment: _know'n'ledge_.

Comment: "all knowledge" while I agree might only what is known,  still strikes me as leaving itself open for what we -will~ one day know.  I don't think "present human knowledge" is redundant .... the notion of "forgotten  is not that arcane IMO nor is the notion of 'future" knowledge terribly odd.    As such, I'd be afraid at least many people would not limit it to "currently known" . "all that humans currently know" ?

Comment: The "set of all knowledge" contains all knowledge, including the single word, if there is one, that means "all knowledge."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pangnosticism**  may come as close as a single word can.

> The doctrine that knowledge is possible concerning everything about which there can be any doubt or real question. [*Wordnik*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/pangnosticism)

The word is derived from the Greek [γνῶσις](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B3%CE%BD%E1%BF%B6%CF%83%CE%B9%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) (I know) with the prefix [Παν](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CE%B1%CE%BD) meaning all

Comment: It does roll off the tongue, but it correctly fits my definition

Comment: *doesn’t, didn’t edit in time

Comment: No it doesn't, but pan-nos-ti-sism could be harder.

Answer (score 1):

*Omniscience* - The second definition at http://www.dictionary.com/browse/omniscience states:

> 2. infinite knowledge.

Comment: This isn’t a good match because it includes the knowledge which can never be known, the unknown unknown.

Comment: In your comment on the original question you stated: I mean all knowledge which we know we know, and know we don’t. – NonCreature0714

Comment: there is knowledge which we know we know and know we don’t know. And then there is knowledge we aren’t even aware we don’t know, and knowledge we don’t even know is wrong. Omniscience certainly covers all of that; but I’m specifically only looking for knowns.

Comment: This seems to be tending toward the philosophical, not grammatical. One could argue that if you know that you don't know of some knowledge that you don't know, then you certainly know of that unknown knowledge. So unknown unknowns are then known unknowns, and still fit into your classification.

Comment: I’m not interested in the philosophy, I’m just looking for a single word which, unfortunately, describes a philosophical idea.

Comment: You make a really interesting philosophical point. I think I disagree a little though because that which is beyond imagination and could never possibly even be conceived is an unknown unknown. How can we know what isn’t even possible to comprehend? That doesn’t mean it can’t become more known at some point. Like a baby in the womb not knowing of any other place — or even being able to do so — thrust into the world, suddenly realizes there is so much it didn’t know, which wasn’t even possible to comprehend in the womb. While in the womb, it didn’t even know what it didn’t know.

Comment: Maybe edit the original question to all discovered knowledge or all known knowledge.

Comment: Having omniscience would mean knowing things outside human knowledge.

Comment: I believe I have found a more suitable candidate word for 'all knowable human knowledge'. Extelligence - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extelligence

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for ***hive-mind*** (which isn't really one word, rather two joined by a hyphen.)

A ***hive-mind*** has the characteristic of a cluster of information nodes where the information is shared among all nodes and results in a ***collective intelligence*** (another two-word candidate).

This can be said of any such group that can collectivize all information for all to access.

Else, there's the ***internet***. (Just kidding.)

Comment: Intriguing suggestion! However, “mind” implies a state of thinking, and thinking is not knowledge — knowledge is still there whether a mind thinks about it or not.

Comment: @NonCreature0714 The problem with the term in it of itself is that the presence of the word "mind" in here has nothing to do with thinking -- The corresponding term might be something like "Groupthink". The "hive-mind" is a collective of information that results in knowledge. For example, the term applies directly to the Internet (as the Internet hive-mind, since we deposit our knowledge there).

Comment: There are a few nuances behind the meaning of “hive-mind” which don’t fit all knowledge or all human knowledge; but, again, quite intriguing. Hive-mind comes close in meaning, but not the quite. Hive-mind sounds very irregular and alien in the context I gave as a replacement for “all knowledge”. Just as importantly, hive-mind is almost always used to describe something not human, like insects or machines; or poor quality social behavior in groups of humans, like group think.

Answer (score 0):

A word for the body of ideas that determine intellectually certain knowledge at any particular time is **episteme**.

Comment: You should include a dictionary definition for your suggested word.